# A 1" T fits the pipe and a 1" valve does not, why?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, pvc, cpvc

Both of these are labeled 1". The T on the left fits the little bit of grey pipe. The valve on the right is too small. What am I missing?

[image: Close up of T, pipe and valve]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That valve is for a different type of piping system called **CPVC** and the sizes and fittings are different. The difference is deliberate because CPVC is rated for hot water whereas regular PVC is not; they don't want people to accidentally (or deliberately, to save money) install regular PVC pipe or fittings on a hot water system.

Look at the valve label.

Comment: Would be worthwhile to refer them to the correct product :) https://www.homedepot.com/p/Homewerks-Worldwide-1-in-PVC-Sch-40-Slip-x-Slip-Ball-Valve-VBVP40E5B/202370033

Comment: I would refer them to a plumbing shop, where the clerk would have been very likely to point out the odd fitting, rather than a "big box" store like Home Cheapo...

Comment: Sure, that works too but I don't know where they live nor whether they have a local plumbing shop with a website catalogue of fittings to look at which I could reference.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You should know that homedepot links can only be reached from the US. Maybe you could use a different reference?

Comment: @AndreKR "1 inch PVC ball valve" in your local language should do the trick. I'm not sure how to satisfy the other 194 countries given that this website itself is targeted for an English audience.

Comment: @AndreKR I can view the link just fine from Australia. I've never heard of an online retailer that only makes their website viewable from a specific country.

Comment: @AndreKR It does work foreign, and it will efficiently place you at the Home Depot nearest you. For instance much of Europe is sent to the Portland, Maine location.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Hm, [this](https://i.imgur.com/rAsOsvx.png) is what I see from Thailand and I remember I get a similar message from Germany. I have heard others complain about the same thing (I think on this very Stack Exchange actually) so I assumed it is from everywhere.

Comment: @AndreKR: To be fair, 193 out of those 194 countries are using metric so they wouldn't care about 1" pipes anyway.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - "_correct_" if you're assuming they A) aren't attempting to rework hot water pipework, and B) live in the US... Perhaps the tee is wrong.

Comment: OP's user profile says California, so US was correct.

Comment: @Attie There is zero reason for me regurgitate the content of the answer unless of course I am trying to appease commenters that fail to read the answer. Hint: I'm not.

Comment: @AndreKR I was led to believe that plumbing is one area where the systems in place prior to metric where still supported to allow for repairing old sites w/o having to replace everything just because of a failure in a single spot.

Comment: @CWHolemanII I think you meant to mention someone else. But since I'm already here... I think plumbing is actually one of four areas where we use inches even in Germany (the others being floppy disks, computer screens and bicycle tires). Of course the plumbing inches have nothing to do with the actual diameter of the pipes, just like anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

When plastic piping systems were first introduce to the market, the manufacturers tried to make them similar to metalic piping systems so "pipers" would accept them. So they adopted similar wall thicknesses to schedule 40 and sch. 80. Piping systems have to be checked against the pressure and temperature of the process fluid. Here in was the problem. Adopting sch. 40 an 80 wall thickness caused inconsistant P-T rates for different sizes of plastic pipe. The solution was to create plastic pipe with a SDR, which stands for Standard Dimensional Ratio. SDR piping has the same P-T ratings regardless of pipe size.

Could one of you pipe and valve components be for a scheduled piping system and the other for a SDR piping systems?

Answer (score 0):

Cpvc and pvc have the same od(outside diameter) and the fittings are interchangeable. The valve is probably just labeled wrong I bet a piece of 3/4 fits the valve just fine